# Getting Gmail emails in read status with Imap PHP

Tags: php, ajax, gmail, imap

I take data from Gmail with this code

```
<?php $data = array(
       // email account
       'email' => array(
        'hostname' => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',
        'username' => $emailAddress,
        'password' => $emailPassword     
       ),
       // inbox pagination
       'pagination' => array(
        'sort' => $sortBy, 
        'limit' => 10,
        'offset' => $offset
       )
      );
      $result = array();

      $imap = imap_open($data['email']['hostname'], $data['email']['username'], $data['email']['password']) or die ('Cannot connect to yourdomain.com: ' . imap_last_error());

$read = imap_search($imap, 'ALL');
 $overview   = imap_fetch_overview($imap, $read[$i], 0);
    $header     = imap_headerinfo($imap, $read[$i], 0);
    $mail       = $header->from[0]->mailbox . '@' . $header->from[0]->host;
    $image = '';
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $read[$i]);
  if(isset($structure->parts) && is_array($structure->parts) && isset($structure->parts[1])) {
                 $part = $structure->parts[1];
            if($part->encoding == 3) {
             $message = imap_fetchbody($imap,$read[$i],1.2);
                $message = imap_qprint($message);

            } else if($part->encoding == 1) {
                $message = imap_8bit($message);
            } else {
             $message = imap_fetchbody($imap,$read[$i],2);
                $message = imap_qprint($message);
            }
        }else{
          $message    = imap_body($imap, $read[$i],0); 
        }
```

?>

All data I receive correctly, however when I enter Email list page, the received emails turn to read.

It worked fine before, after using for some time, this issue appeared.
Any idea what can be the reason?

Comment: Fetching emails marks them as SEEN by default, unless you use the PEEK variant.

Comment: All your code does is login, where's the rest?

Comment: Hi @Max I edited the question. In what function should I use PEEK variant ?

Answer (score 1):

In imap_fetchbody, add the FT_PEEK flag to prevent clearing the \Seen flag automatically.

```
imap_fetchbody($imap, $read[$i], 1.2, FT_PEEK);
```

See option flag documentation at the [official site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php).